# hunspell misses a potential correct word for a misspelled word

Tags: hunspell

For the misspelled word "**perapring**" hunspell does not propose the correct spelling "**preparing**" and only proposes the following words:

- persevering
- pertaining
- innerspring
- preferring
- preprint
- wraparound

Is there a workaround that hunspell proposes "preparing", for example by modifying "**default.aff**" file?
Any solution is welcomed.

Note: I am using "hunspell" through emacs.